# Which site should I migrate this question to?

Tags: discussion, support

I just saw this question, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30311234/cant-install-android-studio-on-ubuntu, on StackOverflow.

I have tried this many times and I never am able to migrate questions to a site located on the migration list:
[image: Migration list]

Obviously this site should be located on SuperUser, for "general" questions, or Ubuntu because it is directly stated in the question, that the user is having trouble installing something on that operating system.

How should I handle migrating this question?

Comment: I would argue that it should *not* be migrated, as it is about a development tool.

Comment: It is about installing a package in a development tool.

Comment: It may be fine on the other sites but it *is* ["software tools commonly used by programmers;"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: You can initiate migration only to this 5 sites. Only mods can migrate to anywhere. SE has numerous restrictions around the migrations, it is one of them. I never understood its exact reason. Thus, it seems we need to live with it. If you flag a post with "other" and suggest a migration to the mods, sometimes they do it.

Comment: @codeMagic It is about downloading packages inside of Android Studio on Ubuntu.

Comment: Yes, packages needed for the development of Android applications...namely part of the Android sdk

Comment: @peterh Honestly, I wish you didn't delete your question, yours makes more since. There is no option to migrate to Ubuntu or SuperUser directly, it seems the "community" thinks the topic is alright.

Comment: @codeMagic So I could start making plenty of posts asking: "How to install , etc for Ubuntu?" on StackOverflow and everything will be ok?

Comment: @JaredBurrows If "etc." were programming tools, and they were good questions in addition to being on topic, then yes.  If you asked about things that weren't programming tools, or you didn't ask clear, answerable questions, then no.

Comment: @Servy Alright, thanks for the clarity, I guess.

Comment: JaredBurrows never mind, @Servy had to be too damn fast and give my answer

Comment: @JaredBurrows You think on my _answer_? I could undelete that.

Comment: @peterh In all honesty, I do not understand the "meta" community very much, if you share an opinion you can get destroyed. So thank goodness, reputation on here does not count. So it guess lets just walk away from this question. I was trying to say that your answer "makes sense" vs "this is a common tool". It was never about the tool, just simply him installing packages for the tool.

Comment: @JaredBurrows I shared my opinion multiple times. The result wasn't fine.

Comment: @peterh Yeah exactly, I guess need to be careful of the questions that I ask on here.

Comment: `There is no option to migrate to Ubuntu or SuperUser directly` ... huh? super user is one of the migration targets in your screenshot. the list of choices is based on historical successful migrations (those where te questions remained open), to try and prevent people migrating things to sites where they just don't belong. Like suggesting someone with trouble compiling something on windows ask instead on Unix & linux.

Comment: @TZHX Yes, I know. I wanted to move it to Ubuntu. I was not sure whether to move it to SuperUser or Ubuntu.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The question is asking about a programming tool, and as such it's on topic on SO.  It should not be migrated.

Comment: I dont' see how that is. It is about downloading packages inside of Android Studio on Ubuntu.

Comment: @JaredBurrows And it's a programming tool that he's having a problem with.  Such questions are *explicitly* called out as on topic in the help center.  It's true *by definition*.  Are you saying that he's not having a problem with a tool, that it's not a programming tool, that solving problems with programming tools isn't on topic on SO or what?

Comment: It was not the "tool", he was downloading a package in the tool. He downloaded and installed Android Studio, then went to install packages, and it was simply missing one on Ubuntu.

Comment: @JaredBurrows Okay, so what's your point?  He was having problems using that programming tool in some way.  That's an on topic question.